# Display Image title over image

Tags: jquery, html, image, css

How do I display image title over image. Code looks like this:

```
<img typeof="foaf:Image" src="galerija
/public/12191388_934693563270076_3046172221632898681_o.jpg?itok=IHAa2J2n" width="900" height="600" 
alt="" title="Foto: Edis Škulj/fkmladost.ba">
```

I want display this over the image `Foto: Edis Škulj/fkmladost.ba`

Comment: That should work when you hover over it. Do you want it to be over the image permanently? http://jsfiddle.net/partypete25/fnb71uLu/

Comment: Yes I want to me on image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use JQuery like this https://jsfiddle.net/a1gqm3nj/

**JS**

```
var title = $('img').attr('title');
$('img').before(title);
```

**HTML**

```
<img typeof="foaf:Image" src="http://placehold.it/900x600" width="900" height="600" alt="" title="Foto: Edis Škulj/fkmladost.ba">
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you are looking for something like this :)

```css
.wrapper {
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  position: relative;
}
img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
span {
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  left: 150px;
  top: 350px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <img typeof="foaf:Image" src="http://www.real-world-physics-problems.com/images/hot_air_balloon_pic_edit.jpg" alt="" title="Foto: Edis Škulj/fkmladost.ba">
  <span>Foto: Edis Škulj/fkmladost.ba</span>
</div>
```

Comment: This one works like a charm. I want this type of solution

Answer (score 0):

Try It Once

```html
<img src="http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/4-Nature-Wallpapers-2014-1_ukaavUI.jpg" title="this is img Title"/>
```